# How to add some more custom controls  in iPod background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

when we press on the Home button two times then we see the all the apps running in the background.if no apps is running in the background then there are only two controls by default.So my question is can we add same functionality in our app? means i want to add some more controls on the background. if yes then how?

Comment: Question is not clear.
You want achieve same(i.e. system background) functionality in your app OR you want add some custom controls to SYSTEM backgroun.(Double tap : Background running apps)?

Comment: @SanjeevRao:i want to add some more custom controls to system background. is it possible? if yes then how can i achieve this?

Comment: @SanjeevRao:is it possible to achieve same thing in some other way?

Comment: its not possible to add we cant change functionality of iphone from our app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add background functionality to your app.

The only ways an application can be controlled in the background are via:

- **Audio events.**  Your app registers and audio session and the user can press play/pause, next, and previous on the lock screen, task bar, or remote headphones.  Unless you're doing audio-specific programming, however, you shouldn't use this.
- **Push notifications.** Your app receives messages from a remote server via Apple's APN, triggered by one of your servers - maybe by a website application.
- **Sensor listening.** It's possible to have your application process in the background inputs from hardware sensors, such as the accelerometer, compass, or GPS.  However, this *kills* battery life and is discouraged unless it is absolutely necessary.

So to answer your question, *no*.